# AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo always returns -50 as an error

Tags: swift

I am trying to figure out how to get the channelmapping info out of the audiounit, but even at the AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo I got stuck with the error -50 (kAudio_ParamError).

I am using Swift and I just can't get this working.

Any ideas from someone who had to deal with this already?

```
func CreateAUGraph(inout player: AUGraphPlayer) {
    CheckError(NewAUGraph(&player.graph), operation: "Couldn't create new AuGraph...")

    //output component description
    var outputcd = AudioComponentDescription()
    outputcd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output
    outputcd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput
    outputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple

    var outputNode = AUNode()
    CheckError(AUGraphAddNode(player.graph, &outputcd, &outputNode),
        operation: "AUGraphAddNode[kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput] failed")

    AUGraphNodeInfo(player.graph, outputNode, nil, &player.outputAU)

    var dataSize = UInt32()
    CheckError(
        AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo(player.outputAU, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &dataSize, nil)
        , operation: "Cannot get size of ch map")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUGraph was not opened yet, so the AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo couldn't hook up to the player.outputAU object as it was not yet existing.

Resolution move this

```
CheckError(AUGraphOpen(player.graph), operation: "AUGraphOpen failed")
```

up after the

```
CheckError(NewAUGraph(&player.graph), operation: "Couldn't create new AuGraph...")
```